# Need explanation on z-index behaviour

Tags: html, css

My CSS code has two squares, green (small, child) and red (big, parent). I want to hide the lower half of small box under big box so that no overlap is visible.

My following code doesn't work but if I remove z-index on the red box, it works.

I can't understand this behaviour. As per my understanding, any -ve z-index on the child will take it below the parent no matter what the z-index on the parent is.
Is it incorrect?

```css
.parent {
  background:red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;/*comment this line to make it working*/
}

.child {
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    position:absolute;
    background:green; 
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By giving the parent element a  `z-index` of its own you establish a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

This causes the `z-index` of the child to be scoped to *inside* the parent instead of scoped to the html element.